# Tinymce click on a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, tinymce, textarea

Im trying to implement a click on a textarea in tincymce through jquery but it does not seem to work. Anyway around this. I am not getting any areas

Thanks

```
$('textarea').click(function( event ){
    alert('trigger');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't do that in that way because TinyMce convert your textarea into an iFrame

Answer (score 1):

The editor is not the same with your textarea. As MiPnamic stated it is the iframe.

You may use the following to install a click handler when editor_id is holding your editors id

```
jQuery('#'+editor_id+'_ifr').click(function( event ){
    alert('trigger');
});
```

**EDIT:** Another thing which should work far better in all browsers will be to use this tinymce init setting (tinymce version **3.x**)

```
setup : function(ed) {
   ed.onClick.add(function(ed, evt) {
     alert('trigger');
});
```

for tinymce version **4.x** use:

```
setup : function(ed) {
   ed.on("click", function() {
    alert('trigger');
   });
});
```

Comment: @Thariama  editor.onClick.add(function(editor, evt) {
             alert('trigger');
         }); Not working for me. Error is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Comment: @DIVA: see my edited answer - it includes the code for tinymce version 4.x

Answer (score 0):

I created a div around that and used the jquery even around that. Alternatively you can use build in functions to catch events built into tinymce found on the following page

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/API3:tinymce.api.3.x